# SMSS: text qualifier in the Tasks > Data Import?

Tags: sql, csv, import, ssms, qualifiers

I am trying to import a file, source [here](https://pxnet2.stat.fi/PXWeb/pxweb/fi/Kuntien_avainluvut/Kuntien_avainluvut__2017/kuntien_avainluvut_2017_aikasarja.px/?rxid=444223df-f91c-4479-891f-5dcd50b983d2) and selections [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwQSk.png) (select all fields and select `"Pilkkueroteltu (otsikollinen)"` and then click `Jatka` to download), with two header rows, " as text qualifier, comma as a field separator and with UTF-8 format. I am unable to do this in Micsosoft Server SQL Management Studio. I will focus now only on the text qualifier where `"` does not work (only reading the first quote as text qualifier).

[image]

[image]

[image]

where I am unable to specify the column separator, no idea why this is occurring.

**Update 1**

---

Refresh/Reset buttons fixed the initial preview but I am getting the following preview error in the step `Select Source Tables and Views` later.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Update 2**

---

I get the LocaleID error `The LocaleID 11 is not installed on this system.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)`. I am getting the same error despite `Locale/Code page` settings, what is causing this?

[image]

**How to specify the text qualifier in the MSMM?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate your scene. Very first, I had to delete first heading entry eg : "Kuntien avainluvut 1987-2016"
Please see : [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5k22.jpg)
Column delimited is: ,

Might not be accurate answer or different from something which you expect, but by applying above settings, I could import data through SSMS2012

**edit** : based on comments.

Here is the detailed steps : 
[image: settings]

next, [image: column delimiter]

next, you need to change column width of first column as it gave me data truncate error[image: change column width]
 next, [image: success]

I have also got a dtsx package for the same, but I don't know how can I share it with you here.

Comment: You can use the `Header Rows to Skip` option with `2` to skip the first two rows, it should work. Does it work for you? What is your text qualifier? Quote "?

Comment: Text qualifier is quote ", that's right. And yes skipping 2 header rows works too. Make sure to click reset column and refresh button(as shown in your image) after making changes.

Comment: I got the initial preview working but the preview later does not work. I added a screenshot to the question, what is causing it? I changed the data types of years 1987-2016 `numeric [DT_NUMERIC]` and the strings to `Unicode string [DT_WSTR]` but the error, ideas?

Comment: Can you please share the exact file you have downloaded ? I will try to replicate here

Comment: [This is the selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwQSk.png) I did [here](https://pxnet2.stat.fi/PXWeb/pxweb/fi/Kuntien_avainluvut/Kuntien_avainluvut__2017/kuntien_avainluvut_2017_aikasarja.px/?rxid=444223df-f91c-4479-891f-5dcd50b983d2) where I selected all fields (all years, everything, command+A) to highlight, then select `Pilkkueroteltu (otsikollinen)` from the bottom selection box and then click `Jatka` to download the CVS file to be imported. This is the preview error I am getting [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIsXI.png).

Comment: @hhh I managed to run with your prescribed settings....I will edit my answer. Hold on.

Comment: I get the error ` The LocaleID 11 is not installed on this system.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)`, are you getting it as well? What could be causing it?

Comment: I moved the Locale error thing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030923/ssms-locale-error-with-umlauts-collation-error), thank you for helping.